# How patches are updated via composer in case drupal core is update?

Tags: php, drupal, composer-php, patch, drupal-8

I tried to update Drupal core 8.3.7 to 8.4.4. But while updating the patches used for 8.3.7 failed. Is there a way atleast to remove patches via composer which arent applicable for new core?  Via command line?

Comment: Sure, remove them from the patches section in composer.json

Comment: Manually? I dont want to remove all. I need to know which is still valid and which is not.

Comment: Yes, manually (the same way you installed it in the first place) - you’re not expecting the computer to rewrite the patch so it applies to the new version of the code or browse the internet to find an updated version, surely :)

Comment: Ok. Got it. Just confirmed if theres some option or not on composer. Because there's lot of patches to check. 

Comment: Assuming you're using cweagan's library, there's an option to ignore certain patches, but again it's declarative rather than automatic. More info here: https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches